# How could I modify this database design to store user history?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, architecture

I have the two tables as pictured below. These are being used to track users current location when they make check-ins at various locations. I'm wondering how I might be able to modify this so I can store users history as well. I want to store all the past locations that a user has checked-in at as well as their check-in and out times.

This could either be adding new columns to the existing tables or some additional tables.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What kind of user history ?

Comment: @Raptor shoot, that would be helpful wouldn't it? I tried to clarify in my edit. Basically just want to know all the locations as user has checked-in at.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of history data you want to store but in general, you can create a *Location* table and *UserLocation* table. In *UserLocation* table you can store check in time, check out time, user id, location id, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can create another table to store the user records:

**Table: rel_user_venue**

```
user_id     venue_id    check_in_time        expiration_time
=============================================================
1           1           2017-08-14 10:01     2017-08-14 11:00
1           2           2017-08-14 11:01     2017-08-14 12:00
```

And change the user table as follow:

**Table: users**

```
id     full_name
================
1      Peter
2      Mary
```

*Note that I change `name` to `full_name` in user table. Always avoid using simple word for column names.*

To fetch the user history, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM rel_user_venue WHERE user_id = 1
```